# Storrm worker issue .daemon.supervisor still hasn't started when using apostrophe char in launcher command

Tags: java, windows-7, apache-storm

I found a weird problem that prevents a worker process to be spawn by the supervisor.: 
The worker launching worker command is using apostrophe instead of quotation.
This is how it look like the firs part of the command:
'd:\tools\java\jdk7_u79\bin\java' '-server' '-Xmx256m' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=46702' '-Dosgi.console=26702'
So anywhere in the command is used ' (apostrophe ) char instaed of " quotation.
 Therefore the worker is not started and in the log of the supervisor I found this kind of messages:

backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor  -dd291770-ae2e-493e-8a1b-42201c36dd09 still hasn't started.

I'm running Storm on Windows 7 with jdk 7u97.

If I'm running the worker command with apostrophe replaced with quotation, then the worker process is started without any issue.

Can you please advise how can I solve this issue? Or what set up should I use for the Windows 7 in order that the worker to use the quotation char?

I look forward for your answers.

Comment: If it works with quots, why not just use quots?

Comment: Supervisor spawns automatically the JVM worker. I've tested manually with the command that Storm provided in the log file just to check what was the error (debugging purpose).

Comment: No idea. I run it on Linux (is Windows officially supported?). Maybe you should ask at user@storm.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite generic. In my case the worker was not started due to a custom application that was launching the Storm cluster. It could not start the JVM for the worker due to the fact that somewhere in the library.path VM property it was path containing the quotation char (").
 I hope that this answer will help others.